# Sending email only when there if a difference in 2 files

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

The below query is checking 2 txt files against each other and sending the difference via email. The issue I have having is that if there is NO difference in the 2 files it still sends out the email.

Is there a way to only send the email out when there is a differnce and does not send a email when there is no difference?

```
class Email:
    def __init__(self):
        self.to = "test@example.com"
        self.frm = "test@example.com"
        self.smtp = "111.222.333.444"
        self.Cc = "test@example.com"

    def sendMail(self,filename):

        body = 'Please see your report attached , <p>'
        msg = MIMEMultipart()
        msg['Subject'] = 'test'
        msg['From'] = self.frm
        msg['To'] = self.to
        msg['Cc'] = self.Cc
        msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'html'))
        part = MIMEApplication(open(filename, "rb").read())
        mailFileBase = os.path.basename(filename)
        part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=mailFileBase)
        msg.attach(part)

        s = smtplib.SMTP(self.smtp)
        s.sendmail(msg["From"], msg["To"].split(",") + msg["Cc"].split(","), msg.as_string())
        s.quit()

with open('main.txt', 'r') as t1, open('Config.txt', 'r') as t2:
    fileone = t1.readlines()
    filetwo = t2.readlines()

outFiletest = 'update.csv'
with open(outFiletest, 'w') as outFile:
    for line in filetwo:
        if line not in fileone:
            outFile.write(line)

email = Email()
email.sendMail(outFiletest)
```

Thank you

Comment: Well, at the very end of your code you just have an instruction `sendMail` which is outside any condition. So it's normal that it always sends the email.

Comment: Also you are just checking that all lines in fileTwo exist in fileOne. This doesn't mean that the two files have NO difference. fileOne can have other lines not present in fileTwo or duplicate lines.

Comment: you able to show me? i have tried by failed

Comment: Use [difflib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html) instead of trying to calculate the diff "by hand", you'll save yourself a lot of trouble.

Comment: @etene, you able to show how to do this?

Comment: The docs have examples that should be enough, I'll post an answer later if you're still stuck

Comment: Sure, i will take a look! thank you etene

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your `sendMail` in a condition.

```
#we define a flag for sending the email and set it to false
do_send_email = False

outFiletest = 'update.csv'
with open(outFiletest, 'w') as outFile:
    for line in filetwo:
        if line not in fileone:
            outFile.write(line)
            # if we enter this condition at least once, we change the flag
            # so the email will be sent.
            do_send_email = True

# if the flag is true, send the email, otherwise do not
if do_send_email:
    email = Email()
    email.sendMail(outFiletest)
```

Having said that, your verification of the two files being equal is not correct. It will only check that all lines in fileTwo exist in fileOne.

If this behavior is fine for you, leave it as is.

Otherwise you can use a `diff` and just send the difference between the two files (which can be lines added, modified or removed)

Comment: thank you for showing me however when i use the above code of yours with mine, i am getting this error - NameError: name 'do_send_mail' is not defined and i only want to check all lines in fileTwo exist in fileOne. i have done that on purpose.

Comment: I defined the variable as email and used as mail, fixed it. But anyway the error you were getting was telling you exactly that, so it's super easy to spot